# Gravity forms limit submission amount

Tags: php, wordpress

so i currently have gravity forms installed with a number of different forms. I want users to be able to see all the forms but only able to submit a maximum of 3.
I found Gravity Wiz Limit submissions, im able to limit the email address to being used 3 times but this is only working for 1 form, i need it to allow users to submit 3 different forms (eg. a global limitation)

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/4024361

having looked through this and then finding

```
add_filter( 'gpls_rule_groups', function( $rule_groups, $form_id ) {
    // Update "123" to the ID of your form.
    $primary_form_id = 123;
    if( $form_id == $primary_form_id ) {
        return $rule_groups;
    }
    $rule_groups = array_merge( $rule_groups, GPLS_RuleGroup::load_by_form( $primary_form_id ) );
    foreach( $rule_groups as $rule_group ) {
        $rule_group->applicable_forms = false;
    }
    return $rule_groups;
}, 10, 2 );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'gpls_apply_limit_per_form', '__return_false' );
```

it looks like its possible but how can i implement this ?

Comment: If you're a [Gravity Perks](http://gravityperks.com) customer (or become one), we'll be happy to provide support via the [support form](http://gravitywiz.com/support/).

Comment: Hi david, the full perks package is just too expensive. sorry

Comment: You won't need the full package, you can get a single perk for $49.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it for a user or guest or both?  By user you could create a user meta and then use the gform_after_submission to add to the meta.  Then use a pre_render to check and see if they are maxed out, and redirect them if they are.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_{form_id}', 'after_submit_{form_id}', 10, 2 );
function after_submit_{form_id}( $entry, $form, $field ) {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$meta_key = 'count_submissions';

$get_meta = get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, true);
$qty = $get_meta + 1;

update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $qty );
}
```

If you need both, you might just create a database table and collect IPs and a submission count.  Then update that on submission.

Comment: ALSO, gravity forms does collect IPs.  If you can figure a way to have the pre_render count the number matching IPs in the $entries.  That could also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help! it's by user - so users have to login to view the forms when theyve logged in theyl be able to submit 3.

Comment: Ya, meta would be the one you want then.  If you used IP then someone can just get on a different device and post more.  Meta if fairly easy.... Maybe I'll post another more complete answer for you...

Comment: that would be ideal mate, i have no clue with php, just need to get this working somehow!

Comment: Weeeeell... I got a snippet for you, but stackoverflow says my answers have been low quality lol if you like this answer, please check it.  Follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/yellowstonebum/4b76faed4c29e65fb01c136b2014c340) for the whole snippet, which includes creating the user meta and the pre_render.  It will need tweaking but should get you most of the way there.  Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou! copied this over to my functions file and replaced {form_id} with 13 which is the form id im testing. This correct? Its giving me error 500

Comment: You may have to play with the Action on line 15.  I put the redirect prompt in there, but it my be the wrong one for the situation.  You can also insert it in parts to narrow down where the problem is exactly.